# MvcCaptcha image does not appear if authentication is turned on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, captcha

SSB.Web.Mvc.MvcCaptcha

The image does not appear if a form authentication is turned on

in the  web.config file:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

[image]

Then the image does not appear

How I fix that ?

the plug in is SSB.Web.Mvc.MvcCaptcha

from http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/mvccaptcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following section to the web.config `<configuration>` section to authorize anonymous access to the `MvcCaptcha` controller.

```
<location path="MvcCaptcha">  
 <system.web>  
  <authorization>  
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>  
 </system.web>  
</location>
```

Comment: @exequielc Sorry, change `<location path="~/MvcCaptcha">` to `<location path="MvcCaptcha">`